# Mysql Large Volume of Queries

Tags: c#, mysql, optimization

What is the best way to optimize a MYSQL server that has 400-1000 queries across 20 tables running against it from 20-30 users?

I have these reports that run against the server and they need anywhere from 400-1000 queries to get all the necessary information. The two issues I am facing are the queries individually are relatively fast but all together take up to 5 minutes to run. The second issue is after about 6 users running reports the whole mysql server just freezes up and I have to restart it. Is mysql not the best choice for this? Any help would be great!

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a pretty dodgy design to me - but you haven't really given enough information.

Comment: I agree with Galwegian. You should check your program design if it's really necessary to run all this queries etc.

But for Server-side optimization I'd suggest to check if you've set indexes and maybe a bigger server. ^^

Comment: It is dodgy design but I was told to concentrate on the database side of things so that is what I am doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check would be that your tables are correctly indexed, this is likely to improve performance significantly if it is not already implemented.

If this data is used for reporting, maybe it would be a good idea to automate the queries and store the results seperately - that way you wouldn't have to run as many queries.